# Get class names in a variable

Tags: jquery

I have this type of code:

```
<ul class="paymentLogo">
  <li class="visa"></li>
  <li class="masterCard"></li>
  <li class="cash"></li>
  <li class="interac"></li>
</ul>
```

How in jQuery I can get:

```
var payments = "visa, masterCard, cash, interac";
```

Comment: Have you read [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com)? Only takes about an hour, and it answers all kinds of questions, including this one.

Answer (score 3):

If you have just the one `.paymentLogo` element, then there are about a dozen ways to get this. Here's one of them:

```
var payments = $(".paymentLogo > li")
                  .map(function() { return this.className; })
                  .get()
                  .join(", ");
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/lubuka/1/)

Or if you want it even more jQuery-ish:

```
var payments = $(".paymentLogo > li")
                  .map(function() { return $(this).attr("class"); })
                  .get()
                  .join(", ");
```

You can find the `$()`, `map()`, and `get()` functions in [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com). Basically, `$()` finds the `li` elements we want to look at, `map` runs the resulting jQuery set past the function we give it to create a new jQuery set with what we return. Within that function, `this` is the `li` element (raw, not a jQuery object) and so we can get a list of its classes from `this.className` (if there's more than one, they'll be space-separated). `.get()` gives us an array for that jQuery set.

Then, the `.join()` call is a JavaScript array function that takes the individual values from the array, converts them to strings if necessary, and joins them together into one string using the separator you give it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I cant see anything wrong with your answer, the question on the other hand....

Comment: It is the question that needs to be downvoted... why the answer for.

Answer (score 0):

try something this:

```
$(pageDetails).find('ul.paymentLogo li').each(function(a) { 
       alert($(this).attr('class')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
var result = '';
$('.paymentLogo li').each(function(){
    var classname = $(this).attr('class');
    result = result+classname+',';
});
alert(result);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukv8m37f/2/)